# Reference entities from a different DbContext

Tags: asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm splitting my DbContext in two: `ApplicationContext` (only domain specific entities) and `IdentityContext` (only asp.net core identity entities).

However, I need to add a foreign key to the `ApplicationUser` entity (`IdentityContext`), pointing to an entity created in the `ApplicationContext`, called `UserArea`. This way, I'll have a table for all company areas and the `Aspnetusers` table will have a column referencing the `UserArea.Id`.

Is the duplication of entities (create the `Area` entity on both contexts) between context the only way to achieve this?

How can I deal with the order of execution of migrations as I may have a table depending on the `IdentityContext` migrations at the same time as a table from `IdentityContext` depending on another table from `ApplicationContext`?

The whole idea here is to have less coupling between the domain layer of my aplication and third party resources like `Entity Framework` and `Identity`.

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<UserArea> UserAreas { get; set; }
}


public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public IdentityContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityContext> options, IConfiguration configuration)
        : base(options)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    public DbSet<UserAudit> UserAuditEvents { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRegistered { get; set; }

}
```

UserArea class:

```
public class UserArea
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Treat those 2 DbContext as separate ones, without any relation between them.** You can use manually assigned ID's (GUIDs) to represent relation between them.

Imagine a 3rd party Identity server and JWT authentication (Auth0, Okta, IdentityServer) - so it's basically an implementation of your IdentityDbContext. The back end will get an unique identifier for that user. See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4 ant the sub value.

Your DB context will need to have:

- an User class as well - it will have a unique ID (best to use integer or sequential guid) and a AuthID - which is the sub from the JWT - and based on you will do all the user lookups
- UserArea object (or DB) - which either has a FK to User.ID or does have User.AreaID or there will be a ternary table for NxN

Anyhow, this should do the necessary decoupling.

Now to user creation:

- either you decide to accept all users from the given identity server
- or you will have to add a boolean: hasAccess flag to the User and also make sure user object is created in your DB when it is added on the identity DB (messaging, callbacks with retries).